# Getting element inner text ONLY when an <img /> tag exists inside using jQuery 's html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the html inside several elements like this:

```
<div class="option s12 pointer"><img class="fl mt2" src="http://web.iboomerang.com/icons/fff/magnifier.png" /> Trainings by date</div>
```

Is there a way to strip the  tag (like PHP's strip_tags does) and leave only "Trainings by date".

Note: I need to avoid using functions like split() or replace(), because of how versatile this app needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this: http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text

Comment: Wow. I've been using jQuery for how long now and I haven't even touched that function?!  Well atleast I know what it does now.

Approved answered, grade A bacon for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery's text() function](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text):

```
var text = $('div.option').text();
```

You can easily replace 'div.option' with whatever CSS selector(s) you need.